# Как можно добавить Webvisor в Android приложение/игру?

Tags: android

есть вот такая [андроид игра](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wiseman.mentalarithmetic)

**Подскажите пожалуйста:** как в неё можно интегрировать что-то типа Yandex Webvisor ??

Answer (score 2):

Точно так же, как и в любое другое android приложение (*имеются ввиду нативные приложения*).

1. В `build.gradle` добавляете зависимость:

   ```
   compile 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:2.60'
   ```
2. Инициализируете библиотеку:

   ```
   public class MyApp extends Application {
         @Override
         public void onCreate() {
             super.onCreate();
             // Инициализация AppMetrica SDK
             YandexMetrica.activate(getApplicationContext(), API_key);
             // Отслеживание активности пользователей
             YandexMetrica.enableActivityAutoTracking(this);
         }
   }
   ```
3. Для отслеживания местоположения требуется разрешение:

   ```
   android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
   ```

Источник: [Подключение и инициализация AppMetrica](https://tech.yandex.ru/metrica-mobile-sdk/doc/mobile-sdk-dg/concepts/android-initialize-docpage/).